# SED commandd to check DATE is palindromic

Tags: bash, sed, backreference

I have file with dates in format MM/D/YYYY, called dates.txt

```
02/02/2020
08/25/1998
03/02/2030
12/02/2021
06/19/1960
01/10/2010
03/07/2100
```

I need single-line SED command to print just palindromic. For example 02/02/2020 is palindromic while 08/25/2020 is not. Expected output is:

```
02/02/2020
03/02/2030
12/02/2021
```

What I did till now is to remove / from date format. How to check is that output the same reading from start and from end?

```
sed -E "s|([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})|\3\2\1|" dates.txt
```

Here is what I get:

```
20200202
19982508
20300203
20210212
19601906
20101001
21000703
```

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/V0snjZ

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it works!. Just to correct it to work with file instead of hardcoded input

Comment: Ok, my hope to see a true `sed` solution is gone with the wind.

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -E '(.)(.)/(.)(.)/\4\3\2\1' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may delete any line that does not match the `d1d2/M1M2/M2M1d2d1` pattern. To check that, match and capture each day and month digits *separately*:

```
sed -E '/^([0-9])([0-9])\/([0-9])([0-9])\/\4\3\2\1$/!d' file > outfile
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -E '/^([0-9])([0-9])\/([0-9])([0-9])\/\4\3\2\1$/!d' file
```

The `^` stands for start of string position and `$` means the end of string.
The `!d` at the end tells `sed` to "drop" the lines that do not follow this pattern.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/K0Tax3).

Alternatively, when you have more complex cases, you may read the file line by line, swap the digits in days and months and concatenate them, and compare the value with the year part. You may perform more operations there if need be:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  p1="$(sed -En 's,([0-9])([0-9])/([0-9])([0-9])/.*,\4\3\2\1,p' <<< "$line")";
  p2="${line##*/}";
  if [[ "$p1" == "$p2" ]]; then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < file > outfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/V0snjZ)

The `sed -En 's,([0-9])([0-9])/([0-9])([0-9])/.*,\4\3\2\1,p` part gets the first four digits and reorders them. The `"${line##*/}"` uses parameter expansion to remove as many chars as possible from the start till the last `/` (including it).

Answer (score 2):

You can backreference in the pattern match:

```
sed -n '/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\/\4\3\2\1/p'
```

Using extended regex and dots looks just nice:

```
sed -rn '/(.)(.)\/(.)(.)\/\4\3\2\1/p'
sed -rn '\@(.)(.)/(.)(.)/\4\3\2\1@p'      # means the same
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works and it is one-line solution